# Workflow Visual Designer Blank

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, visual

I'm using SharePoint Designer to create a workflow.  I have my 2013 workflows all set up but when I click on "Visual Designer" it load assets but then the screen where I assume the diagram should be is just blank. Is there anyway to resolve this?

I've tried re-installing SPD and Visio Professional but nothing has helped.

Comment: is your [Workflow Manager Client](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35375) up to date?
and
Is your SharePoint Designer up to date?